# Entity Framework & Binding synchronisation

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Imagine I have an entity:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbParts">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I bind it to a collection in code-behind:

```
ObjectQuery<MyObject> componentQuery = context.MyObjectSet;
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = componentQuery;
lbParts.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

And the on a button click I add an entity to the MyObjectSet:

```
var myObject = new MyObject { Name = "Test" };
context.AddToMyObjectSet(myObject);
```

Here is the problem - this object needs to update in the UI to. But it is not added there :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528400/ef-code-first-binding-to-listbox/7532473#7532473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectQuery<T>` class doesn't implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, so it doesn't notify the UI when an item is added or removed. You need to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` which is a copy of your `ObjectQuery<T>` ; when you add an item to the `ObjectQuery<T>`, also add it to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Binding :

```
private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myObjects;
...

_myObjects = new ObservableCollection(context.MyObjectSet);
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = _myObjects;
lbParts.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

Add item :

```
var myObject = new MyObject { Name = "Test" };
context.AddToMyObjectSet(myObject);
_myObjects.Add(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The BookLibrary sample application is using an EntityObservableCollection. This way you get always both worlds updated: WPF and Entity Framework.

You can download the sample application here: **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**.